# how to creating sturucture in vb 2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, smartcard

Does anyone know how to create a structure in Visual Basic?

For example:

```
Public SCARD_READERSTATE()
    Dim szReader As String 'reader name
    Dim pvUserData As Long 'user defined data
    Dim dwCurrentState As Long 'current state of reader at time of call
    Dim dwEventState As Long 'state of reader after state change
    Dim cbAtr As Long 'Number of bytes in the returned ATR
    Dim rgbAtr(0 To 35) As Byte 'Atr of inserted card, (extra alignment bytes)

    Public Declare Function SCardGetStatusChange Lib "winscard.dll" Alias "SCardGetStatusChangeA" ( _
        ByVal hContext As Long, _
        ByVal dwTimeout As Long, _
        ByRef rgReaderStates() As SCARD_READERSTATE, _
        ByVal cReaders As Long _
        ) As Long
```

I'm using Microsoft Visual Basic 2008.

Answer (score 0):

You declare a structure like this:

```
Public Structure SCARD_READERSTATE
    Public szReader As String 'reader name
    Public pvUserData As Long 'user defined data
    Public dwCurrentState As Long 'current state of reader at time of call
    Public dwEventState As Long 'state of reader after state change
    Public cbAtr As Long 'Number of bytes in the returned ATR
    Public rgbAtr(35) As Byte 'Atr of inserted card, (extra alignment bytes)

    Public Declare Function SCardGetStatusChange Lib "winscard.dll" Alias "SCardGetStatusChangeA" ( _
        ByVal hContext As Long, _
        ByVal dwTimeout As Long, _
        ByRef rgReaderStates() As SCARD_READERSTATE, _
        ByVal cReaders As Long _
        ) As Long
End Structure
```

However, it looks like that won't be good enough for you. You will need to add a few [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39967861%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to more precisely control the layout of the structure to achieve the proper [marshalling](http://www.vbtonet.com/user-guide-appendix/add-external-marshalling/) for the method. I'm not familiar with the specific method here, but http://pinvoke.net may help you find the [right way to declare this method](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winscard.SCardGetStatusChange) as well as [the right way to build the structure](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures.SCARD_READERSTATE).

The pinvoke.net site is wiki-based, so make sure to add anything you learn to those pages for those who come after you. Most everything on the site is in C# right now, but if you understand the attribute syntax the translation is typically very straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the SCARD_READERSTATE structure from the SCardGetStatusChange Lib "winscard.dll" declaration like so:

```
Public Structure SCARD_READERSTATE
    Public szReader As String 'reader name
    Public pvUserData As Long 'user defined data
    Public dwCurrentState As Long 'current state of reader at time of call
    Public dwEventState As Long 'state of reader after state change
    Public cbAtr As Long 'Number of bytes in the returned ATR
    Public rgbAtr(35) As Byte 'Atr of inserted card, (extra alignment bytes)
End Structure

Public Declare Function SCardGetStatusChange Lib "winscard.dll" Alias "SCardGetStatusChangeA" ( _
        ByVal hContext As Long, _
        ByVal dwTimeout As Long, _
        ByRef rgReaderStates() As SCARD_READERSTATE, _
        ByVal cReaders As Long _
        ) As Long
```